# EasyPHP 14.1 and PHP 5.3

Tags: php, windows, easyphp

I installed EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11 and I need to install php5.3.

I downloaded PHP-5.3.29-for-EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11-setup[1] on this page: [www.easyphp.org] but I don't know how to install it...

Can you help me please ?

EDIT : Read the answer before voting...

Comment: http://www.easyphp.org/introduction.php

Comment: I had read this guide but it doesn't say how to downgrade to php5.3. On homepage it says that easyphp comes with many php version but I own only the last version.

Comment: Download the 5.3 configuration from the components page and install it. http://www.easyphp.org/components.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, see my answer for the problem solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.

When I downloaded the file from the website, Windows rename it to `PHP-5.3.29-for-EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11-setup` instead of `PHP-5.3.29-for-EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11-setup.exe` due to the dot in the name of the file.

So I wasn't able to understand that this file could work with a simple click on it :)

I renammed the file with `.exe` at the end and the problem is solved.

Thanks to people who voted "-1" ... -.-